# Get link to the file returned by a FileContentResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my controller I have created an action that returns images from a database. The images are stored as bytearrays, so I'm returning the contents as a FileContentResult.

In the view, I'm linking to this action with:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", new { id=a.Id })"/>
```

The controller action looks like

```
public ActionResult GetImage(long id)
{
    var article = SolrOperations.GetArticleById(id);
    if (article != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(article.Image) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(article.ImageType))
    {
        var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(article.Image);
        return new FileContentResult(imageBytes, article.ImageType);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This does not yield the desired behavior (even though the images are displayed), as I need the full link to the image, ie: /getimage/id.jpg instead of just /getimage/id. The reason for this is that I want to use ImageProcessor.Web to further process (and cache) the images by supplying a query string in the image src attribute (fx src="myimage.jpg?filter=greyscale").

Comment: This is an old question but you should use an [`IImageService`](http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/extending/#iimageservice) implementation to return the image from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to axtend the link you can just extend your controller method signature, like this:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(long id , string src, string filter)
```

**ASP.NET MVC** will bind this values and on your **View** you can write like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", new { id=a.Id, src = "myimage.jpg", filter = "greyscale" })"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't work. Seems like ImageProcessor still can't interpret this as an image file. Is there another approach for serving a link to the file from the database?

Comment: You simply supply a querystring after the image src, which is then intercepted by ImageProcessor. See an example here: http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/imageprocessingmodule/filter.html

Comment: And how do you understand that it's the image problem? I follow your link and find in documentation this thing: _`ImageProcessor.Web` works by adding a configurable `HttpModule` to your website_. This mean that you don't need controller at all the whole thing is about to configure right `HttpModule` in your `Web.config`. But am I understand correctly that you want get the image from DB and then pass it to `ImageProcessor`? Your Web.config will be usefull in youe question too.

Comment: Well, ImageProcessor is working as it should if I am appending a querystring to any other image. So that should not be the issue.

Comment: And could you just change rendering string of your controller in `RouteConfig`?